# retrieve only first two elements from an array in mongoose also if there is only one then to get only that element?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a field array of strings now i want to get only first two strings from the array now can someone please tell me how to do that also suppose photos r=are only 1 now how to only get first element is there any particular way of doing this i have read about projection, slice operators but couldn't figure out what to use and how, also if i have only one element then in that case would i first have to calculate the size of array to check if its size is greater then 2 then get first two elements otherwise get only one eleemnt ??

Comment: You need to be a bit more specific than this. Are you trying to match properties or do you just want the first two elements regardless. The 2 or 1 or 0 part is not the problem. Just please state what you are really doing. Better yet, show a code attempt ( no matter how bad ) in your question. It tells a lot.

Comment: i only want first two elements no constraint on that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operator is of course [**`$slice`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/slice/) to return just the required elements by indexed positions.

Consider the following sample:

```js
{ "list" : [ 1, 2, 3 ] }
{ "list" : [ 1, 2 ] }
{ "list" : [ 1 ] }
{ "list" : [ ] }
```

If you then use the projection part of a query like so:

```js
db.collection.find({}, { "$slice": [0,2] })
```

Then you are asking for the two elements starting from the `0` index position, which is the first two elements.

Then the result is:

```js
{ "list" : [ 1, 2 ] }
{ "list" : [ 1, 2 ] }
{ "list" : [ 1 ] }
{ "list" : [ ] }
```

So it just does not care how many elements are actually there, it just retrives the elements requested.

Language or framework makes no difference. The operator issued to MongoDB is the only thing that matters. Typically, all "projection" ( which is where you use the operator ) is handled in the second argument to a `.find()` or similar operation.

Comment: Thanx a lot man for your help also can you tell me how to get size of the array with this query if it is possible ??

Comment: @amanverma That is another question and actually a completely different and presently incompatible process for MongoDB at this time. The general suggestion is to just inspect the results returned to the client. However if you think you really need it then pleas [ask that specific question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).